# Help with finding Hex header information of file

Tags: header, hex

I'm not 100% this is meant to go in stackoverflow but I'm sure it'll be moved if necessary.

I have a hex header file I just screen grabbed and would like to know what extension the file really is. The file was originally an exe but didn't seem to work, but looking at the hex information showed that it was an mzp, I just need it to be confirmed.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does look like an [`exe`](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/exe/) file.

Answer (score 11):

It is an executable file created with Delphi. The first 3 bytes 0x4D 0x5A 0x50 are decoded as 'MZP' in ASCII. The "P" stands for Pascal.

Answer (score 2):

MZ - First two bytes indicate dos executable. Not sure what third byte P is for. Might be actually more than one byte and part of program identifier?

http://www.fileformat.info/format/exe/corion-mz.htm

Comment: The P stands for Pascal. This is a Delphi executable.