# Are DLL's from different compilers compatible?

Tags: c, windows, dll, compatibility

We have an application, which loads several DLL's, for example "one.dll". We want to modify "one.dll" by renaming it to one_1.dll and create a new one.dll, which forwards all the existing functions to one_1.dll and just executes some code on attachment (It's unusual, but the circumstances are complicated...).

Here is the problem:
We do not exactly know how the original program was compiled, not even the language. All we can see is that it is 32bit. However the original dll has some weird header ("MZP" instead of "MZ") and the Message "This program must be run under win32".
After we compiled out dll (written in C), our header looked different. For example, it started with MZ instead of MZP and the message was "This Program canot be run in DOS mode".

So my question is:
Are those programs/DLL's compatible, as long as they are both compiled in 32 bit? Even if the main application is written in something like delphi and my dll is written in c? or is there more to look out for?

I can only test it in production, thats why i want to know it beforehand

Comment: It depends on whether the ABI of the DLL's is compatible.  Generally speaking, I believe you can tell compilers to, for example, conform to a CDECL calling standard.

Comment: But proving this in production is unwise.  I suggest you stand up some virtual machines for testing purposes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you. Do you know how I can check the compatibility of ABI's? To be honest I just read about this term the first time. Looks complicated

Comment: [Your MZP header suggests that it is indeed Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531874/help-with-finding-hex-header-information-of-file).  If you can get the interfaces right, you ought to be able to just create your shim DLL's in Delphi, and then call whatever you want thereafter.  That's going to be harder if you don't have the source code for the original DLL.  I can't stress this enough: *you need a test environment to make this work.*

Comment: Do you have any documentation for this DLL? It should tell you about the ABI, because you need it also for your new DLL, because using applications expect the same ABI.